# Unable to ssh from docker container to another server with port 22

Tags: docker

I have created a small docker container with ubuntu 16.04.
Created an ssh key without any passphrase in docker container and added the public key on another server.
Now trying to ssh to server from docker container, Asking for a password to enter.

Comment: Post your Dockerfile

Comment: Is any `ssh` on running that machine (`ps -ef | grep ssh`)? Is something listening on port 22 (`lsof -i :22`)?

Comment: No other ssh is running on docker. Now it is working with ip adress but still having the issue with dns name.